# is app store support ArKitDemo Api for augmentation reality

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality

Hi 
       I am currently working in iphone augmentation reality app in which I have found ArKit Demo API ,But I am not sure that is app store support it or not.

Please give me any suggestion regarding same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about https://github.com/zac/iphonearkit/tree/master/ARKitDemo I have read the code and I see no reason why it shouldn't be accepted.